# Can I store a list of tuples in a QTableWidget? PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt6

I want to store a list as a cell in QTableWidget.

I dont want to display the list I plan on hiding the column that contains the list for each row

I want to use it to access the information in the list based on which cell the user has selected.

Currently im using an array however the problem with this is that the order in which the rows are input can change when I use my search and sort functions simultaneously.

Attempted to set the last cell in each row as a list

I was given the error:

```py
    for x in range(globalStatLen):
        tableBrowse.insertRow(x)
        for y in range(rightLen):
            if y == 9:
                tableBrowse.setItem(x, y, QTableWidgetItem.setData((globalStats[x])[y]))
            else:
                tableBrowse.setItem(x, y, QTableWidgetItem((globalStats[x])[y]))
```

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QTableWidgetItem(type: int = QTableWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QTableWidgetItem(str, type: int = QTableWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QTableWidgetItem(QIcon, str, type: int = QTableWidgetItem.Type): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QTableWidgetItem(QTableWidgetItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
python-BaseException
```

Apologies I cannot post my actual code. Please let me know if my description of my issue is insufficient

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't need to post the actual code, but you're expected to provide a valid [mre], or, at least, the portion of code that raises that error. Btw, use [`setData()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setData) using `Qt.UserRole` (or any value higher than that): `item = QTableWidgetItem()` `item.setData(Qt.UserRole, mylist)`.

Comment: @musicamante I have added the snippet of code that im currently trying to use. 

Using setData I get the error

```TypeError: setData(self, int, Any): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QTableWidgetItem```

Comment: Please read more carefully what I wrote: you need to create an instance of the `item`, then you set its data, and *finally* add it to the table.

Comment: @musicamante Ah I see I apologize. Thank you very much for the help